# C# Outlook MailItem object to byte array without saving Outlook MailItem as a msg file

Tags: c#, outlook

In Outlook add-in I want to convert mailItem object to byte array. It is possible to do this without save mailItem to a specific msg file first and read this file, etc..., or use a third party dll? If it possible, then how?

I already try to find a solution to this, but unfortunately without any success.

Thx.

Comment: Why are you against the MSG file format? Is there a particular reason?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use the MSG format - it preserves the most message properties.

Comment: You think the mailtem.SaveAs function? I am not against the specific msg format. I have to avoid saving mailitem directly to disk.

I should solve this problem (convert mailtem to byte array, or memory stream) without saving mailitem to the disk.

Comment: Outlook Object Model won't let you - a file is the best you can get.

Comment: If I willing to use a third party dll, is there any which is support this? (Convert mailitem to byte array or memory stream)

Comment: I am not aware of any third party libraries that do that. Redemption library does not do that for one simple reason - there is no common stream object supported by all languages that Redemption supports. If performance is your primary concern, creating a temporary file compared to a pure memory buffer adds less than 3% overhead, too small to even measure it reliably.